# Run Firebase on AsynData Nuxt

Tags: javascript, server, nuxt.js

My problem is the firebase request on asyncData method on Nuxt. When the app is on the client the request works but the first load doesn´t work. So, on the server, have i install anything?

This is my code:

```
<script>
 import { db } from '~/plugins/firebase.js'
 export default {
   asyncData (context) {
     let listUsers = []
      db.collection('users').get()
       .then(doc => {
          doc.forEach(user => {
            listUsers.push({ id: user.id, ...user.data() })
          });
       })

    return {
      dataUsers: listUsers  
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried async await? `async asyncData(context){...` and `await db.collection...`

Comment: I have tried it but nothing happens :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see as @Andrew1325 noted, is that you do NOT return a promise from `asyncData`. This means that the server will NOT wait for the request to finish before sending HTML to the client.

On the other hand, how do you access your `dataUsers` in the component?

I suggest you to reformat the code to dispatch an `action`

```
<script>
 import { db } from '~/plugins/firebase.js'
 export default {
   asyncData ({store}) {
     return store.dispatch('FETCH_USERS')
  }
}
</script>
```

And the a simple action

```
async function FETCH_USERS = ({commit}) => {
    const doc = await db.collection('users').get()
    commit('SET_USERS', doc)
}
```

Comment: I see what you say @Borjante. Maybe i can do in that way: async asyncData () { .... await db.collection ..... }